# how to remove values of POST variables

Tags: php, post

can you please clarify my query.. in one part of coding, i would like to initialize or remove the values of POST variables so that the below condition turns TRUE

(!isset(($_POST['abc'])

I did try ($_POST['abc']='') but didnt work as empty value was assigned and !isset condition failed..

hope am clear.. please guide me thro

thanks,

Samuel Mathews.

Answer (score 2):

You can either `unset($_POST['abc'])`, or check `empty($_POST['abc'])` instead of `isset()`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `unset($_POST['abc'])`

[unset](http://www.php.net/unset)

Though generally speaking, best practice is to treat `$_POST` as read-only.  You should instead copy `$_POST` to a diff var for manipulation.